# how can i draw this diagram on lyx (in the most easiest way)? I dont know how to use latex coding

Tags: lyx-layouts

[image]

i also need to add some graphs and staff like that, but I want it to look like a nice official pdf document like we can see on books and reports. Non of the tutorials shows how to do it.. just how to add images.

Comment: There are several graphics packages, but TikZ is most prominant. The manual has lots of tutorials.  You coulod even do it using picture (built in).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In the easiest way: Use a graphical program to draw vector graphics and include the result in your document (for instance Inkscape comes to mind).